# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2014 using ODBC

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2014

I've set up my first SQL Server 2014 and I am trying to connect to it via ODBC, but I'm getting an error:

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client Version 11.00.2100
>
> Running connectivity tests...
>
> Attempting connection [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named
>   Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. 
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> TESTS FAILED!

This is the first SQL Server I've set up, so I apologize if I've missed something rudimentary.

Comment: Have you properly set up tcp/ip?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I have those set up, correctly.  I restarted the service to be sure. Still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade the driver. You need to use the 12.0.4100.1 or above driver to run SQL Server 2014

Comment: I upgraded the ODBC to 12.0.4219.0. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you try Joe C's suggestion to configure TCP/IP. You should not be using named pipes. Also, if you are trying to connect over the network and not locally, make sure the SQL Server services are running with a network account, not a local machine account.

Comment: Yes to both of those.  I double-checked the TCP/IP and restarted the service.  And the SQL Server is running with a network account.

Comment: Can you ping the server?

Comment: Thanks! This led me to the answer.  My hosts file had the wrong IP address in it.